# 'send' does not result in the command being successfully executed in the shell

Tags: shell, tcl, expect, spawn

Consider the following scenario:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect --

#start of the script

proc A {host_ip} {
    global spawn_id
    spawn ssh $host_ip
}

#pattern match using expect statements on the
#output of the spawned ssh process in A
proc B {} {
   expect -ex "$" { send "ls -l\r"; puts "did get this far" } #<------- (1)
   expect -ex "$" { } #<------- (2)
   #find a filename of interest from the output of 'ls' command earlier
   regexp "((a-b\\S+\\s+)+)" $expect_out(buffer) matched file_of_interest  #<------- (3)

   #the following reliably succeeds in sending the intended command, but is obviously pointless
   expect {
        -ex "$" { send "ls -l\r"; exp_continue} #<------- (4)
   }
}

#call the routines
A $some_ip
B

#end of the script
```

My main problem is that at (1) 'send' does not result in 'ls' command being sent, or at least I do not see any evidence of it being sent, but the 'puts' statement still gets executed. The 'puts' statement after 'send' at (1) was placed for debugging purposes only. At (2) I match the prompt with the hope that expect_out(buffer) will contain the output of the 'ls' command. I do not understand why (4) succeeds in sending the command, but (1) does not, consquently, expect_out(buffer) does not contain the desired data.

The 'send' command at (1) should work, but it does not. The 'send' at (4) works, but it is pointless. Is there a way to find out why the 'send' at (1) does not succeed? Any suggestion on improving the reliablity of 'send' at 1.

Thanks.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script. I think the problem is `expect -ex "$"` -- you should not be using *exact* matching here. Try `expect -re {\$ ?$}`

Comment: Well the issue did not turn out to be what I expected, but the new info through exp_internal 1 was useful.